# string compare and remove elements

Tags: matlab, equals, string-comparison

I have a csv file which consists of a N-by-M table.
in the first colum each row consists of 6 different numbers and I need to detect if any of the numbers is identical and then print a error message
This is how I thought it should be writte

```
   valid=true(height(Information),1);
for i=1:height(Information),1;
    if Information{i, 1} == Information{:, 1}
        fprintf('Invalid number in line %d', i);
        valid(i)=false;
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

use third output of `unique` and `histcounts`:

```
% generate two matrices, one with 2 identical elements
A1 = rand(3);
A1(end,1) = A1(1);
A2 = rand(3);
% check identical elements
[~,~,ic] = unique(A1(:,1),'stable');
identicalNumbers = any(histcounts(ic,max(ic)) > 1) % true
[~,~,ic] = unique(A2(:,1),'stable');
identicalNumbers = any(histcounts(ic,max(ic)) > 1) % false
```

**Edit** it can be done even simpler:

```
identicalNumbers = numel(ic) > max(ic)
```

Answer (score 0):

First read the csv file in a matrix called A. then try the following code:

```
    uniqueVals = unique( A(:,1) );% find unique values of col 1
    [r c] = size(uniqueVals);% r determines the number of unique values in A(:,1)
    [rr cc] = size(A);% rr is total number of values in A(:,1)
    if (r~=rr)
        disp('identical numbers detected');
    end
```

Comment: I can't get this to work. 
It won't detect the same value in the colum and then remove it and disp an error message

Comment: I don't know how to write it proporly so it doesn't get messed up

Var1         Var2       Var3    Var4    Var5    Var6

    'S123456'    'Bn'        7       2      10      12  
    'S163765'    'Ayan'        7      10      10      12  
    'S185216'    'Jyan'        4       2      -3      12  
    'S854789'    'Gyan'        7       2       7       7  
    'S325874'    'Zyan'        7       2      10       2  
    'S963256'    'Byan'       12       2      10      12  
    'S123456'    'Name'     7       2       4       4  
    'S214789'    'Hyan'       10       7      10      12

Comment: But This is my test data it is an 8x6 table whit S-number, Name, and grades, and then I have to detect if any of the SXXXXXX are the same and then print an errormessage along with the line number and be able to drag the invalid S-number out, which I think could be done with a logical vector, but if I run your code, it doesn't give me an error message, it just prints identical numbers detected

Comment: My code just detect if there are identical numbers in column 1. if you want to keep unique numbers you can use this part:
        uniqueVals = unique( A(:,1) );
this code asign the unique values to uniqueVals
@Ryan

Comment: If I run this uniqueVals = unique( A(:,1) ), it displays a table 7x1 with the unique values, but it doesn't detect in which line there was an identical number, I've tried to put the uniqueVals commando in my for loop if statement as written in the top, for detecting which line, but it I can't use either = or == in the if-statement

Comment: Do you need the index of rows where there are identical numbers? for example you want to display rows 2 and 3 are identical?

Comment: Yes, I want to print an error message which tells me  if there is a row with the same number, and in which line, and afterwards it should remove the colum 
I've tried with for loop and then using logical indexing for removing all rows = 0

Answer (score 0):

I have modified my code. The below code detect the same numbers in the firs column and tells you the index:

```
    A = randi (8,6)
    uniqueVals = unique( A(:,1) );
    [c r] = size(uniqueVals);
    for i=1:c
        [m n]= size(find(A(:,1) == uniqueVals(i)));
        if m>1
            disp('same values detected in rows: ')
            find(A(:,1) == uniqueVals(i))
       end
    end
```

check the code and give me a feedback.

Comment: I really appreciate you're trying to help so much, but I think maybe I'm not  good enough to explain what my problem is. 
I have an N-by-M table.
The first colum is SXXXXXX second displays name, and the rest is single numbers.
 
I want to look only at the first colum with the SXXXXXX and check if any of the strings in the first colum is identical, If that's the case, it should print an error message consisting of in which line the 2nd Identical number appeares
And then the row should be deleted

Comment: Now, I understand the point you are looking for. if you make a copy of your csv file in a dropbox, I can write the whole code for you.

Comment: put your csv in a file sharing website and send me the link. i'll do the rest.

Answer (score 0):

I have downloaded youe csv file in my local drive. run the code and select the csv file using the dialog box.

```
clear
clc
[file_name, mach_path] = uigetfile( ...
{'*.csv', 'All CSV (*.csv)'}, ...
'Select File');

% If "Cancel" is selected then return
 if isequal([file_name,mach_path],[0,0])
    return

 % Otherwise construct the fullfilename and Check and load the file
 else
        fileName = fullfile(mach_path,file_name);
 end 
 fid = fopen(fileName,'r');   %# Open the file
  lineArray = cell(100,1);     %# Preallocate a cell array (ideally slightly
                           %#   larger than is needed)
  lineIndex = 1;               %# Index of cell to place the next line in
  nextLine = fgetl(fid);       %# Read the first line from the file
  while ~isequal(nextLine,-1)         %# Loop while not at the end of the file
    lineArray{lineIndex} = nextLine;  %# Add the line to the cell array
    lineIndex = lineIndex+1;          %# Increment the line index
    nextLine = fgetl(fid);            %# Read the next line from the file
  end
  fclose(fid);                 %# Close the file
  lineArray = lineArray(1:lineIndex-1);  %# Remove empty cells, if needed
  for iLine = 1:lineIndex-1              %# Loop over lines
    lineData = textscan(lineArray{iLine},'%s',...  %# Read strings
                    'Delimiter',',');
   lineData = lineData{1};              %# Remove cell encapsulation
    if strcmp(lineArray{iLine}(end),',')  %# Account for when the line
      lineData{end+1} = '';                     %#   ends with a delimiter
    end
    lineArray(iLine,1:numel(lineData)) = lineData;  %# Overwrite line data
  end
A = lineArray;
uniqueVals = unique( A(:,1) );
[cc ~] = size(uniqueVals);
for i=1:cc
[mm ~]= size(find(ismember(A(:,1),uniqueVals(i))));
   if mm>1
    second = find(ismember(A(:,1),uniqueVals(i)));
        disp('same value detected in rows: ')
        disp(second(2));
    A(second(2),:) = [];
    disp(A);
   end
end
```

Comment: This code does exactly what I wanted it to do exept if I change the test data file and makes Identical numbers appear more in the testdata file, but thank you for your help I'll try to understand how it works I appreciate all your comments and you're effort for helping me solve the problem

Comment: Youa are welcome. If you want to detect cases that there are more than just two occurance of the identical numbers in column 1, you need to modify the codes in the body of the "if mm>1".

Comment: Why isn't it possible to write second(i) since i loops through the whole dataset and should detect any Identical number and then change it?

Comment: variable second keeps all duplicate values. Assume that I write the A Matrix in the horizontal format as A = [10 2 10 5 10]. Then the variable second is : second(1) = 1 and second(2) = 3 and second(3) = 5.
There is another case when you have more that 1 value that repeated in the whole matrix. Let A = [10 2 10 2 10].

Comment: I get that second holds up the duplicated values, and I understand why second(1)=1, second(2)=3, second(3)=5 in your example above, but in another code, I could replace second('number') with the variable i and then it would change all the time and loop over the whole dataset and detect any value and not just the first one